# Read content of .sst file using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

How can one read the content of a .sst file uisng PowerShell? I know about `Get-ChildItem` and the cert drive, but how can I read from a .sst file instead of the Windows internal certificate stores?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Import it? Extract a specific certificate from the store?

Comment: I want to extract all certificates without knowing beforehand which are inside (effecetively need to convert the file format to a java trust store)